# Excel formula is working for one format of time not for another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am developing the attendance sheet using excel, So inputs are In time and outtime.There are four conditions.

For eg:In time:09:00          Out time:19:30     Ans:  09:30

Formula:

```
IF((AND(L15>TIME(9,30,0),L16<TIME(19,30,0))),L16-L15,<br>IF(AND(L15<TIME(9,30,0),L16>TIME(19,30,0)),"10:00",<br>IF(AND(L15<TIME(9,30,0),L16<TIME(19,30,0)),L16-TIME(9,30,0),<br>IF(AND(L15>TIME(9,30,0),TIME(19,30,0)<L16),TIME(19,30,0)-L15,"0")))).
```

Formula is not working for format like 09:00, but its working for 9:00.

If there are leading zeros in time, then it doesnt work.

Comment: Is the 09:00 time that you enter aligned left or right? If it is aligned left, excel reads it as text.

Answer (score 1):

Your 09:00 time format is most likely read by excel as text. If it is aligned left it is read as text.

Thus you need to change the data that is entered. You could do so with a function that ensures that a number (or time) is entered as text is converted to a number such as `=VALUE()`

Try this:

```
IF((AND(VALUE(L15)>TIME(9,30,0),L16<TIME(19,30,0))),L16-VALUE(L15),<br>IF(AND(VALUE(L15)<TIME(9,30,0),L16>TIME(19,30,0)),"10:00",<br>IF(AND(VALUE(L15)<TIME(9,30,0),L16<TIME(19,30,0)),L16-TIME(9,30,0),<br>IF(AND(VALUE(L15)>TIME(9,30,0),TIME(19,30,0)<L16),TIME(19,30,0)-VALUE(L15),"0"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the cell format to a time format without leading zero, it will not show the leading zero (09:00 is changed to 9:00) and your function should work.

Comment: I tried that  too.But no changes.I used custom option too, but then also no changes.

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish with your formula? 
I tried it in my Excel 2013 and in Excel 2016, and the cell format thing did the trick.

Comment: Those are four conditions,according to in time and out time it will calculated the difference.Min time:09:30 and Max time:19:30.Time difference should be calculated within this time.Hope you understand.